# What is the meaning of "to vanish from casual view"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

To provide context, I've come across the phrase in the following extract:

> More than 900 Stone Age circles, or henges, are known in the British Isles, and there were probably many more of which no trace survives. There are also surviving remnants of old wooden buildings, including some at Stonehenge, alhough these have all **vanished fom casual view**.

Comment: Each word seems to be used in its regular meaning, from a casual view.

Comment: You wouldn't notice them unless you were very carefully looking for them.